# Draw one function, varying color by (gradient) using another function's value

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I'm trying to draw something in Ti*k*Z where I want to vary the draw color.

E.g. I'm drawing this line

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw plot[variable=\x, samples=100,domain=-10:10] ({\x},{sin(deg(\x))+0.6*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But now I want the color to indicate the value of a function, e.g. *c* = *x*<sup>2</sup>.

**Edit**:
With *x*<sup>2</sup> this could then look like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this may be:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [mesh, variable=\x, samples=100,domain=-10:10] ({\x},{sin(deg(\x))+0.6*\x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I just changed the `\draw` environment with `\addplot` within an `axis` environment. This will give you:

[image]

**Update** Fix with `colormaps`. By utilising the `colormaps` tikz library you can set the desired color map and obtain what you desire. As in:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
% Note that this is the colormap definition. You can play with this however you want. Fun fact: this color map also includes 8bit color code definition. Which can be defined using rgb255 = {value,value,value}.
\pgfplotsset{colormap={CM}{rgb=(0,0,1) color=(red) rgb=(0,0,1)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[point meta = y, colormap name={CM}]
\addplot [mesh, variable=\x, samples=100,domain=-10:10] ({\x},{sin(deg(\x))+0.6*\x});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

[image]

**Update** *Credits goes to `@marmot`*.

You can an inline function in `point meta` definition to customise your colormap implicitly using an explicit function (see @marmot's comments).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [ colormap/hot] \addplot [point meta = x*x*x,mesh, samples=100,domain=-10:10] {sin(deg(x))+0.6*x};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, I used cubic function for manipulating the color map. This will give

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think this misses the bit that the color gradient should depict this a function, (in my question i used the example of x^2)

Comment: @sheß Nice that it is close, but could you please explain me the last part? I will try to help you with that :) may be you can draw a small rough sketch on what you would like to get out of it?

Comment: The color should be a determined by the value of f(x)=x^2, so that for example, the color at - 5 should be the same as at +5. I'll work out an example with paint

Comment: clear thanks I will try to cook up something

Comment: @sheß From my understanding, I suppose this is what you desire. Please see updated answer :)

Comment: Thanks, sorry if my question is unclear, but I need to be able to explicitly specify a this as function of *x*. Yours produces something that happens to work for x^2, but does not generalize to what I asked for in the original question ("varying color by another functions value"). x^2 was just an example

Comment: @sheß OOps, in that case, I will wait for some our in house `TikZperts` to answer your question ;)

Comment: @marmot Apparently OP wants to be able to define an explicit function that implicitly manipulates the colormap. I think your proposal is mostly the way to go. However, OP also wants to use custom function `f(.)` in the point meta.

Comment: @marmot I just checked it with your proposal, it works ;) may be you should make that as an answer :D

Comment: Done adding, lately, falcons are going well together with @marmot.

Comment: Great. btw,  whats the policy on removing stuff that's not needed anymore? I think it would be great to delete the two first attempts. It just makes the thing look longer hand harder to find the right info

Comment: @sheB as much as it is nice to remove them, I would prefer to keep them as it gives a chronological evolution.